# EmberJS Model find not up-to-date with underlying store

Tags: ember.js

For a simple overview screen I have a developed a route that sets up a controller that does an App.Location.find().

```
App.LocationsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('content', App.Location.find());
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('locations.index',{into:'application'});
  }

});
```

I naively assumed that this would simply go to the store and fetch me all the records, giving me an up-to-date view of the records.

Apparently not....

- When an external process starts removing records from the database,
  the App.Location.find() keeps on returning these deleted records.
  (although the REST call doesn't show them anymore)
- If an external
  process starts adding records to the database, the
  App.Location.find() picks them up.
- If I delete the records form
  within the Ember app itself the model is correctly updated.

How should I deal with this in my Ember app ? I'd like to have an up-to-date view on whatever is in my database. Right now I need to refresh the page (F5) to get an up to date view. Using the linkTo helpers shows me the stale data.

This seems to be yet another trivial thing that I completely missed in EmberJS. Is it somewhere mentioned in the docs why it behaves like that ? I guess there is a valid philosophy behind this behavior.

My overview screens is simply interested in showing the most up-to-date data. If a record is no longer in the DB the model should not return it anymore.

I've added a [sample project in Github](https://github.com/ddewaele/emberjs-crud-rest) that is having this issues.

Comment: you did post here a similar problem, is this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268434/emberjs-crud-deletedrecord-keeps-re-appearing-after-linkto/16326087#16326087  related?

Comment: no ... the other post mentions a stale data issue when the delete was performed inside the app itself (deleteRecord called on the Model). That was solved with the latest ember.js and ember-data.js. The issue described here talks about deleting a record from the DB outside of the EmberJS app.

Answer (score 2):

Try unloading all of the data from the store before you call find():

```
this.store.unloadAll('widget');
this.store.find('widget');
```

That will fully refresh your store to reflect what's on your server.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing when faced with tis issue. Now my problem is I can't find a way to refresh the currently rendered template. Isn't there any way in Ember to just re-render the template based on the new data? this.transitionTo doesn't work for the same template, this.set('model') doesn't re-render. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried App.Location.query() instead of App.Location.find()?

Comment: This seems to work as it now notices the deleted records when I return to the overview screen, however all my actions on the overview screen (adding / remove records) don't work anymore. (I've updated the question with my github project that is experiencing the issue).